# Extjs text field label at bottom

Tags: extjs, textfield

Is it possible to put label at bottom of text field?
I'm required to have the UI look like a PDF/printed form where most of the field labels are centered below input fields.

A CSS style/class approach is good enough.  I just want to get this over in a hurry.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Add a custom cls to your textfield as follows:

```
    Ext.create('Ext.Panel',{
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        width: 300,
        height: 500,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'First Name',
            cls: 'pdfField',
            labelSeparator: ''
        }]
    });
```

Then create the pdfField class:

For ExtJS (5) =>

```
div.pdfField .x-form-item-label {
    display: table-footer-group;
    text-align: center;
}
```

For ExtJS (4) =>

```
.pdfField td {
    display: table-caption;
}

.pdfField tr>td:first-child {
    display: table-footer-group;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Here is a fiddle ta works with both versions: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/h35

Not that it looks better with ExtJS 5, that is because in ExtJS 5 uses divs to display the textfield content while ExtJS 4 uses table cells.

Comment: This works in 5.0.
Do you have a code that works in 4.2.x? 
Thanks for the reply